# Is there a way to create a list of property values from a list of some type?

Tags: linq, list, c#-4.0

Imagine that I have this class:

```
class Person
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Surname { get; set; }
    string Other { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `IList<Person>` and now I want an `IList<string>` that is a sequence of the `Name` of each person.

I can use this loop:

```
var Names = new List<string>();
foreach (Person p in Persons)
{
    Names.Add(p.Name);
}
```

But, I would like to know if linq (or any other option) allows me to do it more easily?

Thanks.

Comment: If you get the question right ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lstPersons.Select(x=> x.Name).ToList()
```

Comment: `p` is better than `x` :-p, +1

Answer (score 3):

like this?

```
var Names = Persons.Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = new List<Person>();
items.Add(...);
items.Add(...);


var people = items.Select(x=>x.name);
```

Comment: are people names? Is an `IEnumerable<string>` an `IList<string>`?